# How to use cookie with electron & angularjs

Tags: angularjs, session, cookies, electron

I use electron with angularjs (electangular : access to all electron method in angularjs) and i want to set a cookie.
I make this in my controller :

```
    var BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
    var app = electron.app;

    var session = electron.session;
    var ses = session.fromPartition('persist:name');

    BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()[0].webContents.session.cookies.set({
            url: 'exemple.fr',
            value: 'guid',
            expirationDate: 1568277822
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

And i've got this error when i set the cookie : Error: failed
    at Error (native)

Thanks for you advice

Comment: Have you did this? Now I am working with Electron app using Angular js how can i access electron cookies value in angular js?

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the 'http://' in your url to make

```
http://.exemple.fr
```

even if your cookie domain is following the wildcard format of '.exemple.fr'